# How to check which compiler was used to produce a binary

Tags: gcc, arm, binaryfiles

For cross compiling code for ARM processor, we have a GCC tool chain and a tool chain from ARM. Is it possible to check if a binary file was compiled using GCC tool chain or ARM tool chain.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you could try dumping the .comment section

```
objdump --full-contents --section=.comment yourprogram
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the same for SREC format?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an ELF file, check if it has a `.comment` section - many compilers write their identification string there. Otherwise, you may have to resort to checking the binary code. It's not trivial, but definitely doable. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18722413/422797) for details.